# Integration of Elastic Search and Camunda BPM?

Tags: elasticsearch, integration, camunda, camunda-modeler

**How to integrate Elastic Search with Camunda ?** I am trying to integrate ElasticSearch to Camunda BPM there

i tried using this project: https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-elasticsearch

But unfortunately it's a dead end project please guide me.
Also i didn't found any docs.